# Vectorize summing values that belong to a group

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorize a loop that goes through different index mappings? For example:

```
a = zeros(1, 5);
m = [4 3 5; 5 1 3];
f = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];

for ii = 1:size(m,1)
    a(m(ii,:)) = a(m(ii,:)) + f(ii,:);
end
```

Gives output:

```
a = [5 0 2+6 1 3+4] = [5 0 8 1 7]
```

Can this be done without the `for` loop?

Comment: What are `afunction1` & `afunction2`? Also few parameters are undefined in `map` function.

Comment: They are just some functions that gives a matrix of size `n_B`. `map` is a inline function giving a vector of indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  `accumarray` works by providing a set of keys and a set of values associated with each key.  `accumarray` groups all values that belong to the same key and does something to all of the values.  The default behaviour is to sum all of the values that belong to the same key together, which is what you're after.

In your case, `m` are the keys and `f` are the values you want to add up that belong to the same key.  Therefore:

```
>> a = accumarray(m(:), f(:))

a =

     5
     0
     8
     1
     7
```

In general, you may have keys that are missing.  Therefore, you may opt to specify the output dimensions of the output array where it should be the **maximum** key value seen in `m`:

```
a = accumarray(m(:), f(:), [max(f(:)), 1]);
```

This is of course assuming that `f` consists of strictly positive values.

In general, if you have floating point numbers in `f`, then `accumarray` out of the box won't work because the keys are assumed to be strictly positive and integer.  However, a common trick is to assign a unique ID to each value of `f` and use this as the input into `accumarray`.  The third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) should do this for you.  You'll also need the first output of `unique` to help you figure out which sum belongs to what key:

```
[msorted,~,id] = unique(m);
a = accumarray(id, f(:));
out = [msorted a];
```

`out` will contain a 2 column matrix where each row gives you a unique value in `m` and the associated sum for all values that shared the same key in `m`.